# Parsing throw JSON with Python - String indices must be integers

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse through json data with Python 3.
My objective is to get all the cities from the JSON and add them to a list:

```
cities = []
for component in userdata['tagged_places']['data'][0]['place']['location']:
    cities.append(component['city'])
```

Python returns me this error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

This is what my JSON in variable userdata looks like:

```
    {  
   'id':'1234',
   'tagged_places':{  
      'data':{  
         'created_time':'2017-12-31T02:33:31+0000',
         'id':'1234',
         'place':{  
            'id':'455149097983173',
            'location':{  
               'city':'Buenos Aires',
               'country':'Argentina',
               'latitude':-34.59537,
               'longitude':-58.39196,
               'street':'Rodriguez Peña '               '1165, Recoleta, '               'Buenos Aires',
               'zip':'C1020ADW'
            },
            'name':'La Cholita'
         }
      },
      {  
         'created_time':'2017-11-04T13:43:00+0000',
         'id':'1234',
         'place':{  
            'id':'58666790576',
            'location':{  
               'city':'Concepción',
               'country':'Chile',
               'latitude':-36.829561426349,
               'longitude':-73.036282767458,
               'street':'Víctor Lamas '               '#1290',
               'zip':'4070386'
            },
            'name':'Universidad de Concepción'
         }
      },
```

My objective is to return Concepcion & Buenos Aires to my cities list.

If I do

```
city = userdata['tagged_places']['data'][0]['place']['location']['city']
```

city gets returned correctly.

Comment: If your bottom code works, then what is your question?

Comment: after doing the for loop I get the error that I mentioned. I do not understand why I get the error. This prevents me from adding all the cities to the list.

Comment: Neither of those snippets can *possibly* work, because `['tagged_places']['data']` is a dict not a list. Show your *actual* data and code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`userdata['tagged_places']['data'][0]['place']['location']` is a `dict`. Hence, you can just access a key as you do via

```
userdata['tagged_places']['data'][0]['place']['location']['city']
```

Iterating a `dict`, however, produces its keys, which in your case are strings:

```
for component in userdata['tagged_places']['data'][0]['place']['location']:
    print(component)
    # 'city', 'country', etc.
    component['city']  # cannot work:  'city'['city']
```

If you want to collect all the cities, you should do sth like:

```
# assuming data is a list, which it appears to be given your working code
for component in userdata['tagged_places']['data']:  
    cities.append(component['place']['location']['city'])
```

Comment: Awesome! That works. However,  cities.append(component['place']['location']['city']) still gives me a KeyError: 'city'. But all cities get collected in the list

Comment: @robjeiter Your code breaks, but the cities get collected anyway - you lost me there :) You should post an extract from your *actual* data in the question as has been pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Key Error comes because sometimes city is not provided by Facebook. All clear now. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your items...

```
mydict = userdata['tagged_places']['data'][0]['place']['location']
for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
    print key
    print value
```

Try this and see if you can see your data....